# PHPUnit filter on group

Tags: phpunit

I am working on re-configuring our php unit test setup and ran into a need to run tests that belong to a specific group by only if they also belong to another group.  For example, I may have something like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @group Alpha
 * @group area1
 */
class TestAlpha extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTest1() {
        ...
    }

    public function testTest1() {
        ...
    }
}

/**
 * ...
 * @group numeric
 * @group area1
 */
class TestNumeric extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTestA() {
        ...
    }

    public function testTestB() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I only want to run tests from `area1` group, I would use

```
phpunit --group area1
```

However I also need to be able to run tests from `area1` group but *only* if they also belong to `numeric` group.

If I run `phpunit --group area1,numeric`, the tests will be included if they are in one **or** the other group.  How can I run phpunit to only include tests if they are in one **and** the other group?  Sort of like `--filter` parameter but on a group level.

Just to note, I'm dealing with an existing suite of several hundred test classes and massively restructuring the tests (e.g. in separate suites) isn't something I can afford at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. `phpunit --list-group -c selenium.xml selenium/`

by using this list all groups

2. `phpunit --exclude-group alpha --group numeric -c selenium.xml selenium/`

exclude group which you don't want to use like alpha